# a reference problem with tag <a> reference element by id #element

Tags: angular, dom, tags, href

Please help with this,

I have a tag in my HTML document with an Id:

[the tag with id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKxLc.png)

The problem is, when i use a call by reference the screen doesn't move. The call by reference:

I try in two way, both don't work:

way 1:

[using router link and fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmTu8.png)

way 2:

[using only href with #id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/istGy.png)

please help

I try in two ways

I expecting other way from somebody

Comment: way 2 should work. 
Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9ky8tp?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

See that when you import the RouterModule.forRoot, you can add a "routerOptions"

In this function you can include routerOptions

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled', //<--this makes the trick
  scrollOffset: [0, 64], //<--this is for not just in the anchor
};

const routes: Routes = [ ...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

NOTE: source and credits to [Quân Đỗ](https://quandh19.medium.com/). In this [link](https://quandh19.medium.com/how-to-enable-anchor-scrolling-of-angular-router-in-the-right-way-42e9b19657b5) He show how you can makes smooth the movement in anchor subscribing to router.events instead of use the routerOptions

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    viewportScroller.setOffset([0, 50]);
    router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof Scroll)).subscribe((e: Scroll) => {
      if (e.anchor) {
        // anchor navigation
        /* setTimeout is the core line to solve the solution */
        setTimeout(() => {
          viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
        })
      } else if (e.position) {
        // backward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
      } else {
        // forward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Eliseo thanks for your help. I used in the routing.module the configuration.